# how to make JMS best performance and reliable in design?

Tags: java, jms

If we use JMS to handle real-time message, for example, real-time stock price message, how to make it best performance and reliable in design ? for example, should use queue or topic ? if message arrived, it should saved into database first ...., do we need use transcation ?

If this code can achieve realtime

```
public void onMessage(Message msg) {
        final long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        Thread timer = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(true){
                    if((System.currentTimeMillis()-currentTime)>processTimeLimit){
                        // send message back to server, processing time is over the limit
                        break;
                    }                   
                }           
            }           
        });
        timer.start();

        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {             
                // save to db
            }});
        t.start();      
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The performance of your messaging is not up to the JMS layer, but the underlying implementation. E.G. WebSphere MQ, Tibco EMS, Apache ActiveMQ, Oracle AQ, etc.

You should use a queue if you wish to send to one recipient (i.e. process) only, but use a topic if you want to have many recipients read the a copy of each message. This is a design issue.

You need transactions if losing a message before it was processed would be detrimental to your application. Or if having a message half-processed is detrimental. In most circumstances, you will need to use transactions.